# How to execute the Data in chunks or Batch wise in loop using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table which have 20 million records . I have recently added another column to that table.
I need to update the data into that column.
I'm using MYSQL community edition, when I execute the direct update like this :

```
Update Employee SET Emp_mail = 'xyz_123@gmail.com'
```

System Getting hanged and Need to close the execution abruptly.
But when I update the statement with filter condition it is  executing fine.

```
Update Employee SET Emp_mail = 'xyz_123@gmail.com' where ID <= 10000;
Update Employee SET Emp_mail = 'xyz_123@gmail.com' where ID >= 10000 AND ID <= 10000 ;

--------
--------
no of  Times
```

Now I'm looking  for looping  script where I can execute in chunk wise.

For example in SQL it is  like this but I'm not sure of MYSQL:

```
BEGIN 
I int = 0 ;
cnt = 0 ;
while 1 > cnt
SET  i = i + 1; 
Update Employee SET Emp_mail = 'xyz_123@gmail.com' where ID >= cnt AND ID <= I

END
```

Note : this is a random script syntax wise there may be some errors . Please ignore it.

I'm looking for Looping  in MYSQL

Comment: what about subquery with limit for update?

Comment: any approach is fine as long as  it is updating in Batch wise  @AnkitSharma

Comment: Maybe mention the Adhoc part in question itself

Answer (score 0):

In a row based database system as MySQL, if you need to update each and every row, you should really explore a different approach:

```
ALTER TABLE original_table RENAME TO original_table_dropme;

CREATE TABLE original_table LIKE original_table_dropme;

ALTER TABLE original_table ADD emp_mail VARCHAR(128);

INSERT INTO original_table SELECT *,'xyz_123@gmail.com'
FROM original_table_dropme;
```

Then, maybe keep the original table for a while - especially to transfer any constraints, primary keys and grants from the old table to the new - and finally drop the `%_dropme` table.

Each update, in a row based database, of a previously empty column to a value, will make each row longer than it originally was, and require a reorganisation, internally. If you do that with millions of rows, the effort needed will increase exponentially.

Comment: I don't have  drop permissions @marc this will not  going to help me

Comment: Talk to the dbadmin about the problem. He will very probably let you - as the strain on "his" database will be much lower with this approach than with the update.

Comment: Or, thinking about it: can you drop the `emp_mail` column, and then: `ALTER TABLE original_table ADD emp_mail VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'xyz_123@gmail.com'; ` ? DDL commands could be less intrusive than DML, where you need to be able to roll back if something goes wrong.

Comment: I'M looking in loop statement only